# Zend AMF custom dispatcher

Tags: php, zend-framework, dependency-injection, amf

Is it possible to use a custom dispatcher when using Zend_AMF?

I know I can pass either a class name or an object to setClass() for Zend_AMF.

However, when I pass an object to setClass, it does not seem to store a copy of that object. Instead it worksout the class name and then instantiates a copy of the object itself.

This is a problem as I use the yadif dependency injection container. Objects should be instantiated with constructor dependencies and/or property dependencies.

Since the Zend_Amf dispatcher does all the instantiating, I am not able to inject constructor dependencies and other dependencies to my objects.

If anyone has a strategy as to how I can overcome this without touching any of the code in Zend_AMF, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to basically build a wrapper around Zend_Amf. The way it is written means that I had to copy most of the code in the handle and _handle() methods. I then had to modify some called methods to point to an instance of Zend_Amf I have created.

Finally, the dispatching was changed so that my own dispatcher was called, and the results returned.

Obviously not the most elegant solution, but hopefully they will rework Zend_AMF to be a bit more extensible in the future and allow us to hook into it much easily.

At the moment, I can still easily drop in an updated version of Zend_AMF into my "vendors" folder without modifying any of the code.